# What type of 24 VDC to 730 V converter is this?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, full-bridge

The circuit below converts 24V DC into 730V. The circuit looks like a flyback converter but from what I know with the full-bridge rectifier at the output it can't behave like a flyback.

The feedback connection is actually via a voltage divider and an optocoupler but I just simplified it for easing the sketch(when the output is 730V optocoupler is activated and the PWM generator decreases its duty cycle).

Transformer's N2/N1 ratio is 40, and the PWM generator's output is at 33 kHz.
I thought this is not a special type of converter what it does only boosting the voltage which is kind of AC because of PWM switching by dividing the input by turns ratio of the transformer but after some measurements I'm a bit confused.

[image]

Here is the drain terminal voltage of the MOSFET( in yellow) and the gate voltage( in pink):

[image]

From the drain voltage measurement it can be said that the primer voltage of the transformer oscillates between -14 and +16 V, but from what I think how this circuit works the peak value of the output is supposed to be 16*40= 640V which is not true. This is where I'm confused.

I've tried disconnecting the bridge rectifier and replaced it with a diode and circuit works almost exactly same.(except the current increased with time but that must be because of the heat on the diode)

What I want to know is that how this circuit can output 730V with the full-bridge rectifier at the output.

I'm sorry for the lousy hand sketch and photo quality.

Here is the schematic I got:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKsMZ.png

Comment: Show the proper circuit. Don't use words to add in modifications to the circuit. The circuit IS king and not the words. Also reveal where the design comes from or how you stumbled across it. Add data sheet links to the MOSFET, the bridge rectifier, the controller chip and anything else of importance you mentioned in words (that you will now reveal in a proper schematic). Are you also hiding a snubber circuit across the primary? Hint - don't hide anything.

Comment: There is only the schematics of the circuit and it looks quite complicated, I tried to simplified it without touching the main concept.

Comment: Don't simplify it.

Comment: We like complicated circuits ;-) so humour us. You can also include **both** the real and the simplified circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Flyback without galvanic isolation, and a poor one.

If your schematic does not match reality ("*The feedback connection is actually via a voltage divider and an optocoupler but I just simplified it for easing the sketch*"), then it does provide galvanic isolation.

If you simulate it, you will see that two of the diodes may or may not be forward biased when the transistor is on and the circuit will operate in forward mode, but it depends on your output voltage, transformer inductance, transformer leakage inductance, winding direction (I assumed flyback in the schematic below) and switch frequency. When the switch is off and any energy is stored in the core (or air gap), it's a flyback.

[image]

I'll let you experiment at determine if more energy is transferred during the flyback or forward period. Hint: Vary the output voltage and observe what happens.

Comment: Yes that's what I was typing.
Although the circuit works it doesn't make sense to me with the bridge rectifier.

EDIT: The rectifier can be viewed via the link https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/on-semiconductor/GBPC3510/1057388

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by  
"you simulate it, you will see that two of the diode may or may not be forward biased when the transistor is on and the circuit will operate in forward mode, but it depends on your output voltage, transformer inductance and switch frequency."

Comment: I think that means you're supposed to simulate it and see what you can see.

Comment: @TimWescott Correct. Own simulations and form your own understanding > asking and getting answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you a lot for devoting your time for the simulation I suppose it helped a lot. I had tried to simulate it multiple times but due to the poor component selection none of them were succesful.

Let me explain what I've grasped from the concept of this circuit via simulation:

When the switch is on primer voltage rises abruptly and allows current to flow by time creating a magnetic field inside the core of the transformer. During this time the voltage across the primer coil is reflected to the seconder side by 40 times.

When the switch is off current through the primer coil stops flowing suddenly and the coil increases the voltage at the drain terminal because of the huge change in its current. An deven though there’s no current through the primer, because of the magnetic energy stored in the core(during forward mode) current flows through the seconder I explain this like magnetic energy in the core discharges to the seconder coil.

Are there any problem about the way I explain this circuit?

Comment: You are trying to explain how a flyback converter is operating. It is true that current stops flowing on the primary side of the transformer when the switch is turned off, and you can analyze the entire operation from current in each coil, but I find it less intuitive than reflected voltage. If you want to learn how a flyback operates, the circuit in your OP is a bad example since it is a flyback/forward hybrid during the entire charging period. Anyway, you have posted this as an answer to your own question, but it’s formulated more as a new question. Please take the Tour from the link below.